# How to upload file with additional information in java

Tags: java, file-upload, common-files

I am using apache `commons-fileupload` to upload file. But, I'm unable to pass more information about the attachment. For example, users want to add attachment information while uploading the particular file. So I send the comments together with attachment. But use commons-fileupload, I only get the attachment, but I can not get the comments. The code below is the form

```
<form action"taskcontroller" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="filename_1">File: </label>
        <input id="filename_1" type="file" name="filename_1" size="50"/><br/>
        comments:<input type='text' name='comments' />
        <input type="submit" value="upload" name="command" />
</form>
```

and the code below is to process the request,

```
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);  
if (isMultipart) {  
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);  
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);  
    Iterator iterator = items.iterator();  
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
        FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();  

        if (!item.isFormField()) { //ignore the form element  
            String fileName = item.getName();  
            // TODO filesize int is it ok?  
            int size = (int) item.getSize();  
            String root = "";//Set the root  
            File path = new File(root + "/uploads");  
            if (!path.exists()) {  
                boolean status = path.mkdirs();  
            }  

            item.write(uploadedFile); //write file to disk  
        }  
    }  
}
```

but i can not get comments information...

Comment: if your problem resolved, then accept helpful answer, otherwise let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check for from field `isFormField()` and retrieve details of fields `getFieldName()` and `getString()`

```
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);  
if (isMultipart) {  
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);  
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);  
    Iterator iterator = items.iterator();  
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
        FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();  
        String name;
        String comment;

   //Check for Form Field i.e. Comment field

        if (item.isFormField()) { 
        name= item.getFieldName(); //Comment Field Name
        comment = item.getString();  // Comment
        }

      //Check for attachment field

        if (!item.isFormField()) { //ignore the form element  
            String fileName = item.getName();  
            // TODO filesize int is it ok?  
            int size = (int) item.getSize();  
            String root = "";//Set the root  
            File path = new File(root + "/uploads");  
            if (!path.exists()) {  
                boolean status = path.mkdirs();  
            }  

            item.write(uploadedFile); //write file to disk  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file to server attach an unique id to the photo and for comments store it in comments table and also store photoid in comments table inorder to uniquely identify comments for the photo.